# Using conditional expressions

Tags: trigonometry

I did:

```
Solve[Cos[x] == 1/2, x]
```

And got:

```
{{x -> ConditionalExpression[-(π/3) + 2 π C[1], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}, {x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[π/3 + 2 π C[1], 
    C[1] ∈ Integers]}}
```

Can someone give me an example of using these ConditionalExpressions, maybe to plot the Cosine and the line y=1/2 and fill in the point of intersection? Haven't used these ConditionalExpressions yet.

Comment: Why don't you check Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/ConditionalExpression/Scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's about plotting things and extracting the information you need. Here's one way: give the answer a name and then evaluate it over a range of the integers `C[1]`. Extract from this the x-values and then calculate the corresponding y-values. Then plot the curves and the points, and combine with Show:

```
ans = Solve[Cos[x] == 1/2, x];
xValsRule = (ans /. C[1] -> Range[-3, 3]);
xVals = Flatten@xValsRule[[All, 1, 2]];
yVals = Cos[xVals];
Show[Plot[{Cos[x], 1/2}, {x, Min[xVals], Max[xVals]}], ListPlot[Thread[{xVals, yVals}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful answer. Much appreciated.

Comment: The Min and Max idea was a good one. And the ConditionalExpression part outlaws attempts such as ans /. C[1] -> 1/2 and ans /. C[1] -> Sqrt[2], both giving replies of {{x -> Undefined}, {x -> Undefined}}.

Comment: Because of your help, I can also do: Plot[{Cos[x], 1/2}, {x, Min[xVals], Max[xVals]},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[Thread[{xVals, yVals}]]}]. Maybe the first time that the Thread command is starting to stick in my head.

Comment: `Thread` is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

You could also specify a domain of interest. If you just wish to plot the intersections you could use `MeshFunctions`:

```
roots = {x, 1/2} /. Solve[Cos[x] == 1/2 && -6 Pi < x < 6 Pi, x]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[roots]}]
Plot[Cos[x], {x, -6 Pi, 6 Pi}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
 Mesh -> {{0.5}}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}]
```

[image]